# Plotting Labels on NVD3 scatterChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

If I have the following code from the example at http://nvd3.org/examples/scatter.html, can I add a label to the plotted points? Not a tooltip, but have one of the values in my data render as a label which is always attached to the point? Obviously doing that in this specific example would be way too crowded, but in a less sparsely populated chart, it would be great to label if each point has a name. Thank you!

```
  nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)    //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
                .showDistY(true)
                .transitionDuration(350)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  //Configure how the tooltip looks.
  chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
      return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
  });

  //Axis settings
  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

  //We want to show shapes other than circles.
  chart.scatter.onlyCircles(false);

  var myData = randomData(4,40);
  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(myData)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});

/**************************************
 * Simple test data generator
 */
function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
  var data = [],
      shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
      random = d3.random.normal();

  for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: 'Group ' + i,
      values: []
    });

    for (j = 0; j < points; j++) {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: random()
      , y: random()
      , size: Math.random()   //Configure the size of each scatter point
      , shape: (Math.random() > 0.95) ? shapes[j % 6] : "circle"  //Configure the shape of each scatter point.
      });
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add labels. This is pretty cheesy, but gives an idea:

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll('path')
    .each(function(scatterpoint) {
        svg.append('text')
             .x(scatterpoint.x)
             .y(scatterpoint.y)
             .text(scatterpoint.maybe_you_have_text_here);
    })
```